# how to pass my custom variables to my payment procedure when customer is click on the payment button?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am creating a table of my services or products where each product have their id next to it.
I want to grab that product id into the URL of buy now button when customer click on that button, and when customer have done their shopping , that custom id should return back to my site within success URL.

I am want this to activate their each product when customer had done their payment using their specific button next to their product.

and that product is only activated when its id come back with its success URL.

because here is multiple items thats why I am trying to use their unique id.

if there is only 1 product, then I shouldn't use this method.

[image: image example]

I am also using payza and also want to use this same method into that.

any idea how can I do this?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to paypals developer page. They have some examples. If  i remember correct you can provide the id in a special variable when you link to paypal. You will get it back as a POST request along with transaction ids, when you get that POST back you should remember to request Paypal again to verify that it was legit

To get the id into the URL: If you already have it in a database why not just echo it directly into the url?

EDIT:
To send the information needed to paypal you make a form like this. It should be sent as a post so you can't use a simple link:

```
$paypalbutton = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.BS_BUSINESS.'">'; 
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.BS_SHOPNAME.'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'.BS_PAYPALCUR.'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$total.'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="'.$shipping.'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$cartid.'">';

$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="'.$customer['bs_firstname'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="'.$customer['bs_lastname'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="'.$customer['bs_address1'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="'.$customer['bs_address2'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="city" value="'.$customer['bs_city'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="'.$customer['bs_zip'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="state" value="'.$customer['bs_state'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$customer['bs_email'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="'.substr($phone,0,2).'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="'.substr($phone,2).'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.BS_RETURN.'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="country" value="'.$postage['bs_country_isocode2'].'">';
$paypalbutton .= '<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="'.BS_IMAGE.'">';

$paypalbutton .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!" value="Go to Payment >"></form>';
```

As you can see I'm passing my shopping card id in the key 'custom'. This key value you will get back. The 'return' is the link where paypal redirects your user after the purchase. This is not where you get your values back. It is just so you can show a message like 'Thank you for shopping at my shop'

After the payment Paypal sends all values to the link you specify. You shouldn't use the GET method (the ? and the key/value pairs after the link)
Paypal is sending all neccesary data back as a POST request to your link I think you call it member.php

NB: VERY IMPORTANT. These data you get back you can't trust. Because anybody can send these data to your return link. So after receiving the return data you sent it all back to Paypal to verify that it was a legitimate request. You will then get back an 'OK' and then you are good to give the customer their goods. Hope this helps.

Comment: so when I echo it in the buy now button's url, will I get it back when the customer have done their shopping?

example `http://www.example.com/member.php?active=94` like this?

Comment: You have to figure out the right key. Must admit I can't remember the key name. You use 'active' that probably won't work. It could also be that you should use a POST request and not GET like you do.

Comment: Please try to look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ What I'm talking about is the classic API. My implementation is old but there are now more options for integration

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://jdmweb.com/how-to-easily-integrate-a-paypal-checkout-with-php

Comment: well this tutorial isn't helpful me, there is only integration of checkout, which i am not using. I just want to get those ids back with success url either with POST or GET method when transaction is done.

Comment: the PP developer docs is too frustrated me, :( there is too much links and text that is confusing me and make me no sense where to start and implement that into my site :(

I need a really simple and easy solution, all i want is that only jus get back my product ids with their success url.

and it could only be dynamically, but when we setup the return url in the pp options that is not dynamically that is static, and I alwasy get that same static url what I dont want.

Comment: So how can I verify this data sending back to paypal? means how can I send this to back paypal? and I tried the single link too and that works :) the link looks like 

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=EK‌3N3ZNRP62PE&notify_url=https://www.example.com/member.php&custom=".$domainId."`

but the problem is that I get it back as GET how can I get this values into POST? and as you can see my custom pass in this link, I get it back as cm= , why I get like this format in the url?

Comment: I have get the url looks like

`https://www.example.com/member.php?tx=21D02439XL489414E&st=Completed&amt=0%2e01&cc=USD&cm=96&item_number=1`

note that my `custom` variable is changed to **`cm=96`**

Comment: It has been a while since I used the paypal api, but please try to look at some example code here: http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/  It is unfortunately not very simple to set up paypal. But maybe with their new apis it has become simpler